# Graphical representation of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I'm having trouble visualizing the graphical representations of linear combinations of vectors. For example, how come I can represent the equation $$x_1 \vec{a}_1 + x_2 \vec{a}_2 = \vec{b},$$ where $\vec{a}_1$ and $\vec{a}_2$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, in both of these two ways?    [Graph 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwLul.png) [Graph 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRUSY.png)

Comment: You have to do the same procedure as your Graph1.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It represent a **plane**, it is not really simple to visualize in $\mathbb{R^3}$.

A way is to use graphical software or in alternative draw some **line intersection** of the plane with the plane x=0, y=0 z=0.